# Python script from Cloud9 IDE trying to upload to AWS s3 bucket showing "No such file or directory"

Tags: python-3.x, cloud9-ide

I am working a college assignment where one of the steps is to upload an object into an S3 bucket using Cloud9 IDE. After trying in my main code, I did some research and found a youtube video tutorial that I that I copied the code below.

This code is still throwing the no file or directory error even though the file clearly is created. I have tried specifying the path directly and moving the text document around but nothing seems to work. I am not sure what else to do, seems like no matter what directory I point to, cloud9 says there's nothing there.

```
import os
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = 'fname-lname-102823'
cur_path = os.getcwd()
file = 'hw1-object.txt'
filename = os.path.join(cur_path, 'data', file)

print(filename)

data = open(filename, 'rb')

client.upload_file(filename, bucket, file)
```

```
Nester - SD40
└── Homework1
    ├── file_upload.py
    └── hw1-object.txt
```

Comment: Hi Nesterino  welcome. I've answered your question to help you but before asking future questions, please don't just copy and paste code without learning what each line does. Read about [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) & anything that you might not understand - it will be a great habit to develop for the rest of your college course. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your file structure, this is incorrect:

```py
filename = os.path.join(cur_path, 'data', file)
```

The `data` folder doesn't exist; try:

```py
filename = os.path.join(cur_path, file)
```